# Cygwin : error: package net.jradius.packet.attribute does not exist

Tags: cygwin, package, javac

This doesn't appear to be the usual CLASSPATH issue, but maybe something specific to cygwin.
The following illustrates the issue.

```
import net.jradius.packet.attribute.AttributeFactory;

public class Test{

 static int x = 100;
}
```

When compiling the following error appears.

```
$ javac Test.java
Test.java:1: error: package net.jradius.packet.attribute does not exist
import net.jradius.packet.attribute.AttributeFactory;
                               ^
1 error
```

The file jradius-core-1.1.4.jar is in the CLASSPATH.

When using the command line within Windows it works. Here is the classpath.

```
 set CLASSPATH=c:\Temp\jradius-core-1.1.4.jar
```

When using cygwin it produces the error. Here is the classpath.

```
 export CLASSPATH=/cygdrive/c/Temp/jradius-core-1.1.4.jar
```

The location is valid via cygwin as the following shows it is recognized.

```
ls  $CLASSPATH
/cygdrive/c/Temp/jradius-core-1.1.4.jar
```

The same JDK is used for both scenarios. 
Any idea why it may be failing via cygwin???

Answer (score 1):

You are using JDK built for windows, so the environment is for windows.

That's being said, you should be provide windows-style path to javac.

**cygpath** is what you are looking for here.

Try:

```
javac Test.java -cp `cygpath.exe -w /cygdrive/c/Temp/jradius-core-1.1.4.jar`
```

*cygpath -w* means print in windows style.

Or just put the **jar** file in the *same* directory of the java file, and in cygwin:

```
javac Test.java -cp jradius-core-1.1.4.jar
```

Refer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690756/how-to-run-java-from-cygwin)

Comment: I have read similar threads about this but the strange part is when using the /cygdrive/c... reference (for other JAR files) to build numerous other things it works without issues. Will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Added the JAR files into the directory and changed the classpath to include '*' and that appears to have worked.