# Calling liquibase commandline from Cygwin

Tags: bash, liquibase

Trying to run a call to liquibase from command line (bash script). This works if I run it on a server (Red hat linux) but i get an error if I run it from a cygwin prompt:

```
java -cp ../liquibase-core-3.1.1:../ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar liquibase.integration.commandline.Main --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \
    --changeLogFile=database/master.xml --url=${schema_url} --username=${schema_username} --password=${schema_password} \
    --contexts=${schema_context}  migrate
```

I get the error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class liquibase.integration.commandline.Main`

Can't see why.

Comment: What is the output from `which java` on cygwin?

Comment: Points to Java installation on C drive. Java JDK 1.7.0_51

Comment: The classpath entry `../liquibase-core-3.1.1` should be `../liquibase-core-3.1.1/*`

Comment: Tried but no effect...

Answer (score 2):

Found a way around the problem. Created a liquibase.properties file with the information,

```
url: <url>
username: <username>
password: <password>
contexts: global,dev
driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
classpath: ../ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar
changeLogFile: database/master.xml
```

And called the liquibase CLI using

```
java -jar ../liquibase-core-3.1.1.jar --defaultsFile=../foo/fum/liquibase.properties migrate
```

This worked fine both on the server and on cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Java on CYGWIN has problems to resolve PATHs. To make this add

```
cygwinpath -wp
```

To fix this problem replace

```
java -cp ../liquibase-core-3.1.1:../ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar
```

with

```
java -classpath \`cygpath -wp ../liquibase-core-3.1.1:../ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar\`
```

Remember to surround `cygwint -wp <path>` with this mark  `

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises because Java expects a windows style path but the liquibase script issues a unix style path. See also the discussion [how to run Java from cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690756/how-to-run-java-from-cygwin). The proposed solution is to fix it by means of cygpath.

The root case is something different though. If you look into the startup script for liquibase you see the following piece of code

```
# build classpath from all jars in lib
if [ -f /usr/bin/cygpath ]; then
  CP=.
  for i in "$LIQUIBASE_HOME"/liquibase*.jar; do
    i=`cygpath --windows "$i"`
    CP="$CP;$i"
  done
  for i in "$LIQUIBASE_HOME"/lib/*.jar; do
    i=`cygpath --windows "$i"`
    CP="$CP;$i"
  done
else
  if [[ $(uname) = MINGW* ]]; then
    CP_SEPARATOR=";"
  else
    CP_SEPARATOR=":"
  fi
  CP=.
  for i in "$LIQUIBASE_HOME"/liquibase*.jar; do
    CP="$CP""$CP_SEPARATOR""$i"
  done
  for i in "$LIQUIBASE_HOME"/lib/*.jar; do
    CP="$CP""$CP_SEPARATOR""$i"
  done
fi
```

That is the script checks for the existence of cygpath and will fix the issue if it finds it. Chances are that you are lacking cygpath.

If `which cygpath` results in `/usr/bin/cygpath` then everything should work as expected. Otherwise you have found the root cause.

This raises the question why cygpath is missing and how to get it. In my case I removed my (outdated) installation of git / gitbash and installed the newest version. This came with an up to date gitbash which included cygpath as desired.

Answer (score 0):

check the main class jar file "liquibase.jar" in the main

Comment: Hi, welcome to the club. You 'd better to explain your answer.

Comment: Agreed with @Yasen, your answer could be a guidance, but at it's current state it's pretty ambiguous.