# Running Java Program on Cygwin - classpath not found

Tags: java, linux, windows, cygwin, classpath

I have a simple Java program that prints out my classpath. Folder structure is as follows:

```
[~/tmp/bin]# ls
launcher/  PrintClasspath.class*
```

And a copy of the same class one more level down in.

```
[~/tmp/bin/launcher]# ls
PrintClasspath.class*
```

When I jump up to my `~/tmp` directory and run `PrintClasspath` in my `~/tmp/bin` directory, I can run the program just fine, stating `./bin` as the classpath.

```
[~/tmp]# java -cp "./bin" PrintClasspath
/C:/Cygwin/home/user/tmp/bin/
```

Or I can run the same file I nested in the `~/tmp/bin/launcher` directory if I edit the classpath as follows:

```
[~/tmp]# java -cp "./bin/launcher" PrintClasspath
/C:/Cygwin/home/user/tmp/bin/launcher/
```

But when I try to sit in my `~/tmp` directory, and try to run my class in the `~/tmp/bin/launcher` directory with `./bin` as my classpath and qualify where the class is located via the following:

```
[~/tmp]# java -cp "./bin" launcher.PrintClasspath
Error: Could not find or load main class launcher.PrintClasspath
```

It FAILS. I've run the same test on my Linux box, and qualifying where the class is located in a sub-directory after giving a classpath multiple directories up works fine.

I originally assumed this was a Windows/Cygwin nuance, but I tried the same exercise in Windows command prompt and same result. What am I missing here.do I just have to run my Windows Java programs with a fully qualified classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: When setting the classpath in Cygwin using the Windows version of Java, you have to use the `cygpath` utility with options `-wp` to convert the unix style paths to Windows paths.

```
[~/tmp]# java -cp `cygpath -wp ./bin` launcher.PrintClasspath
/C:/Cygwin/home/user/tmp/bin/
```

(via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690756/how-to-run-java-from-cygwin))

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer. I can not comment yet. I wanted to note that this helped me with a problem where I was running javac -cp foo:bar/none which worked on Mac OS.  In cygwin on windows it did not work, giving multiple errors about not finding a project xxxx in bar/none. xxxx was already compiled in bar/none.  Using cygpath -wp foo:bar/none solved my problem. Example

```
javac -cp `cygpath -wp foo:bar/none` -d out/whatever/there src/*.java
```