# Starting Java Program (jmeter) within cygwin

Tags: java, jmeter, cygwin

Big fan of cygwin, having trouble starting jmeter (which is a Java program) from within Cygwin.

I can get it to work just fine, but java doesn't seem very fond of having "/cygwin" in the path to the JAR file.  So, I can just pass in the path to the JAR file using a relative path, but that's pretty inconvenient as I move around the file system.   Here's a sample to illustrate my issue:

```
[NA+CBURKIN@WLPF0SGDR4 perftest (chad)]$ which java
/cygdrive/C/PROGRA~1/Java/jre1.8.0_71/bin/java


NA+CBURKIN@WLPF0SGDR4 perftest (chad)]$ java -jar /cygdrive/c/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile /cygdrive/c/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar

[NA+CBURKIN@WLPF0SGDR4 perftest (chad)]$ java -jar ../apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar
================================================================================
Don't use GUI mode for load testing, only for Test creation and Test debugging !
For load testing, use NON GUI Mode:
   jmeter -n -t [jmx file] -l [results file] -e -o [Path to output folder]
& adapt Java Heap to your test requirements:
   Modify HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx512m" in the JMeter batch file
================================================================================

[NA+CBURKIN@WLPF0SGDR4 perftest (chad)]$ ls -l ../apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar /cygdrive/c/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar
-rwxrwx---+ 1 NA+CBURKIN NA+Domain Users 13739 Apr  9  2017 ../apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar
-rwxrwx---+ 1 NA+CBURKIN NA+Domain Users 13739 Apr  9  2017 /cygdrive/c/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar

[NA+CBURKIN@WLPF0SGDR4 perftest (chad)]$ diff ../apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar /cygdrive/c/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also a big fan of Cygwin!  Does this not work for you, or it's unsuitable?

```
GlassJ@PHX99-LT51-4709 /cygdrive/c/Users/GlassJ/Desktop
$ /cygdrive/c/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/java -jar "c:\Users\GlassJ\Desktop\Main.jar"
Hello world
```

It's running a simple hello World test.

Other option I can/could think of possibly trying to set the directory delimeter then unset it when the jar has run.

Comment: You solved my puzzle !  It didn't occur to me that when passing the full path of the jar file, java will be looking relative to Windows, not relative to cygwin.   So as you did, I now specify the full path to java.exe relative to cygwin, but the jar file should be specified relative to c:\

Comment: So in my case, assuming the windows java.exe is in your PATH, the proper call is:

`java -jar "C:/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar"`

Comment: Really glad I could help out!  Cygwins also a bit funny if you need a lot of classpath entries, if you ever run into a problem like I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488352/running-java-program-on-cygwin-classpath-not-found) might help you out and save you a lot of time!  Happy CygWin'ing!

Comment: Thanks so much, very helpful !