# Why the jar file cannot be find in cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I am new to sygwin, so I am probably doing something wrong.

Here is my shell script:

```
!/bin/sh
set [-x]
export myInstallDirectory='/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/uTrace_ServerMachine'
echo "myInstallDirectory=" $myInstallDirectory
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Java_JDK_SE_8_u77_64_bit
echo "JAVA_HOME = " $JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
echo "PATH =" $PATH
export CLASSPATH=$myInstallDirectory/bin/UtraceServer.jar:$CLASSPATH
echo "CLASSPATH=" $CLASSPATH
java -jar UtraceServer.jar
set [+x]
```

Here is what the log shows:

```
myInstallDirectory= /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/uTrace_ServerMachine
JAVA_HOME =  /cygdrive/c/Java_JDK_SE_8_u77_64_bit
PATH = /cygdrive/c/Java_JDK_SE_8_u77_64_bit
```

/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WinZip/WINZIP/WINZIP32.EXE:/cygdrive/c/Java_JDK_SE_8_u77_64_bit/bin:/cygdrive/c/Java_JDK_SE_8_u77_64_bit/lib/tools.jar:/cygdrive/c/Java_EE_SDK_7_u2/glassfish4/bin:/cygdrive/c/Java_EE_SDK_7_u2/glassfish4/glassfish/bin:/cygdrive/c/Java_EE_SDK_7_u2/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/javaee.jar:/cygdrive/c/IBM/Derby/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/lib/derbynet.jar:/cygdrive/c/IBM/Derby/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/lib/derbytools.jar:/cygdrive/c/IBM/Derby/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/lib/derbyoptionaltools.jar:/cygdrive/c/IBM/Derby/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/test/jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar:/cygdrive/c/IBM/Derby/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/test/derbyTesting.jar:/cygdrive/c/IBM/Derby/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/lib/derbyrun.jar:/cygdrive/c/IBM/DB2_EX~1/java/db2java.zip:/cygdrive/c/IBM/DB2_EX~1/java/db2jcc.jar:/cygdrive/c/IBM/DB2_EX~1/java/sqlj.zip:/cygdrive/c/IBM/DB2_EX~1/java/db2jcc_license_cu.jar:/cygdrive/c/IBM/DB2_EX~1/bin:/cygdrive/c/IBM/DB2_EX~1/java/common.jar:/cygdrive/c/ORACLE/NetBeans 8.1/java/maven/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:/cygdrive/c/Cygwin/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Network Monitor 3:/cygdrive/c/My_Software_Development/Client_Monitoring/Client_Scripts

CLASSPATH= /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/uTrace_ServerMachine
/bin/UtraceServer.jar:.;C:\Java_JDK_SE_8_u77_64_bit\lib\tools.jar;C:\Java_EE_SDK_7_u2\glassfish4\glassfish\lib\javaee.jar;C:\IBM\Derby\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\lib\derbynet.jar;C:\IBM\Derby\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\lib\derbytools.jar;C:\IBM\Derby\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\lib\derbyoptionaltools.jar;C:\IBM\Derby\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\test\jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar;C:\IBM\Derby\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\test\derbyTesting.jar;C:\IBM\Derby\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\lib\derbyrun.jar;C:\IBM\DB2_EX~1\java\db2java.zip;C:\IBM\DB2_EX~1\java\db2jcc.jar;C:\IBM\DB2_EX~1\java\sqlj.zip;C:\IBM\DB2_EX~1\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;C:\IBM\DB2_EX~1\bin;C:\IBM\DB2_EX~1\java\common.jar

Error: Unable to access jarfile UtraceServer.jar

The jarfile UtraceServer.jar is located in  /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/uTrace_ServerMachine/bin/UtraceServer.jar 
and as you can see it is in the CLASSPATH.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Java is not a Cygwin application so it can not understand its 
PATH nor the cygdrive suffix.

JAVA_HOME =  `/cygdrive/c`/Java_JDK_SE_8_u77_64_bit
PATH = `/cygdrive/c`/Java_JDK_SE_8_u77_64_bit

Comment: I don't think this is correct. There is even a doc on the Internet that explain how to make Cygwin  use the Java environment installed on the Windows machine. For some reason it does not work in my case.

Comment: I am not saying that is impossible to use the windows JDK, just that you can not do it in that way.

Comment: matzeri, This is correct, but I included the location of the Java installed on the Windows machine in file .bashre.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [How to run Java from Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690756/how-to-run-java-from-cygwin/16538153#16538153), you can use Cygwin paths in your script, but just before you call Java, you should convert them to Windows paths, for instance with `cygpath -p`:

```
!/bin/sh -x
export myInstallDirectory='/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/uTrace_ServerMachine'
echo "myInstallDirectory = $myInstallDirectory"
export CLASSPATH="$myInstallDirectory/bin/UtraceServer.jar:$CLASSPATH"
echo "CLASSPATH = $CLASSPATH"
CLASSPATH="$(cygpath -pw "$CLASSPATH")"
echo "CLASSPATH (Windows) = $CLASSPATH"
java -jar UtraceServer.jar
```

(I've omitted the other paths from the script, because Java is clearly found.)

`cygpath` can (among others) convert a single path between POSIX and and different Windows formats, e.g. `-w` converts a path to a Windows path. With the addition of `-p` it treats its argument as a path list (separated by `:` for POSIX, by `;` for Windows). See `cygpath --help` for the full info.

Important: when you use this in scripts, it is recommended always to use double quotes (as in the script above). Doing this consistently considerably reduces the risks for issues caused by (e.g.) spaces in path names.